VMWare VSan FileServices Error
I'm getting the following error when trying to create a file services domain with VSan in VMWare ESX
File server fqdn suffix should be in dns suffix list.
This particular message is not found on google.
I checked the DNS suffix on all of my esx hosts, and they all have the DNS suffix I am creating.
I  checked the suffix on my vcenter appliance, and changed that.
I have double checked the DNS names that the IP's resolve to. They are all correct.
I'm at a loss. I don't know where else to check for the DNS suffix list. Every option I could find related to DNS Suffixes is correct. Every page in vcenter. Every link.
The only area I noticed was missing suffixes is in vApp properties for the appliances created for file services after enabling it. It was empty but I can't find a place to set that, so maybe it's supposed to be.
I have also tried turning off VSan and turning it back on, still didn't work. I have restarted VCenter, still nothing.
Does anybody have any ideas?

Are you using a .com or trying to trick it to do so?
